# DataGrid additional column and row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

```
<DataGrid Name="grid"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsReadOnly="False"
              HeadersVisibility="None"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              AutoGeneratingColumn="c_dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">

public static DataView GetBindable2DArray<T>(this T[,] array)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(Ref<T>));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    int a = i;
                    int b = j;
                    Ref<T> refT = new Ref<T>(() => array[a, b], z => { array[a, b] = z; });
                    dataView[i][j] = refT;
                }
            }
            return dataView;
        }

public class Ref<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T> getter;
        private readonly Action<T> setter;
        public Ref(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter)
        {
            this.getter = getter;
            this.setter = setter;
        }
        public T Value { get { return getter(); } set { setter(value); } }
    }
```

Thats  my code. And i got this DataGrid:


[image]

But Here is extra row and column. How to show only my grid 5x5 without empty row?

Comment: what do you get for **GetLength()** and you sure gotta work on the variables !

Comment: GetLength(0) and GetLength(1) is the length of first and second dimensions of 2d array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to check the return values of GetLength(0) and GetLength(1) to make sure that they do what you expect them to. In addition, I always had one additional row (to create a new row on the fly) when I used Data Grids.

Update:
The additional row disappears when you set IsReadOnly to "True" (like I said, it is made for on the fly edits) and the additional column is not a real column, it is the space of the row header, shown on the right. It disappears when setting  HeadersVisibility to "All" or "Row".