# Can a Func return an L-Value?

Tags: c#, func

I'm attempting to see if I can make the following code work with non null-able types.  I recently discovered that value types act "strangely" when used as `ref` parameters - they can be null..

[image: sorry about the screenshot - the code is on a secure VM]

Is it possible to return an "assignment target" from a function such that the scenario described by the following code may be realized?

```
void Main()
{
    // want to call F and assign the result to _result
    CallAndAssign(() => F(), () => _result);
}

int F()
{
    return 1;
}

int _result;

void CallAndAssign<T>(Func<T> functionToCall, Func<T> memberToAssignResultTo)
{
    // As I suspected, this did not work, "left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer" 
    //memberToAssignResultTo() = functionToCall();
}
```

I realize I could do this by making the second parameter an Action and simply perform the assignment, but that's not really different than doing the same thing on the next line of code.

My intuition is that, if this **is** possible, then it will involve the use of Expression, one of the last C# topics I've yet to wrap my brain around to a useful degree.

Comment: Why do you want it? Can you provide some code of what you want to simplify/avoid with it? I don't see the problem of doing `_result = F();`..

Comment: You are right, you would have to use `Expression<Func<T>> memberToAssignResultTo` to be able to break the lambda down and then use reflection to update the property. As an `Func<T>` you can't.

Comment: Look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339602/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-the-return-of-references

Comment: Looks like "I'm off to see the Lippert...." :)

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: yeah I know, it was on a secured VM (obviously the code is generic enough that I didn't worry).. just being lazy